# Operator !! producing unexpected result

Tags: c++

I have a problem relative to some C++ code about the `!!` operator. It gives me an unexpected result and I don't understand why:

```
int x=-12; 
x=!!x; 
print("value=",x);
```

The output of this is `1`. But i do not know how. Can anyone explain this ambiguous result?

Comment: `!(-12)` is `0` and `!0` is `1`.

Comment: Nothing ambiguous, or undefined here. See the answer from **Bathsheba**.

Comment: If `1` is an unexpected result, what result did you expect instead?

Comment: we don't understand why "1" was unexpected by you. If you would explain that in the question, it would be even easier to provide precise answer explaining you where you went wrong. (I mean in this case the answer should explain it well, this is more like advice how to produce even better questions in the future)

Comment: !(-12) kindly explain this expression.

Comment: Note that `!!` is not an operator. It's two operators.

Answer (score 5):

`!!x` is grouped as `!(!x)`.

`!x` is 0 if `x` is non-zero, and 1 if `x` is zero.

Applying `!` to that reverses the result.

So, `!!x` can be viewed as a way of setting `x` to 1 if it's not zero, and remaining at 0 if it's zero. In other words `x = !!x` is the same as `x = x ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: It's an excellent 'trick' I came across in somebody else's code some years ago. Maybe just worth noting that `!!` is not an operator, but the concatenation of two `!` operators.

Answer (score 0):

> ... !(-12) kindly explain this expression.

It's "logical not of -12". In C++ numeric value `0` is `false` in logical way, and any non-zero value is `true` in logical way. This is how C and C++ evaluates numerical values in boolean context, like `if (expression) ...`, i.e. `if (-12) exit(1);` will exit your application, because `-12` is "true".

When you typecast numeric value to `bool` type and then back to `int`, the true will become value `1`, but most of the time you can avoid these conversions and use intermediate results of numerical calculations directly, where any non-zero value is "true".

So "not of true" is value `false`. I.e. `!(-12) == false`. And `!false == true`. And you convert the logical value "true" back to `int`, which will make `x == 1`.

The `!!(numeric_value)` is idiomatic way in C++ (and in C too) to "normalize" any numeric value into precisely 0 or 1 (and you may encounter it in source code of many applications).

The "logical" distinction is important, because C++ has also binary operators, where the calculation is working per individual bits, not with value as whole. In "binary" way the "!" operator sibling is `~`. Similar example to yours with bit-complement operator `x=~~x;` would then result into original value `-12`, because every bit of `x` is flipped twice, ending with same value as it did start. So `~~x` is not something to encounter in regular source, as it's basically "no operation" (contrary to `!!` which is "no operation" only if the original value was already 0 or 1).

Also this is sometimes source of bugs for people learning the language, as they forget about the distinction and write something like

```
    if (4 & 2) { /* this is "and" so it should be true??? */ }
    // it will be false, because in binary way 4&2 == 0

    if (4 && 2) { /* this is logical "and" and will be "true" */ }
    // because 4 is non-zero, 2 is non-zero, and "true and true" is "true"
```

I.e. binary operators are `& | ~ ^` (and, or, not, xor), and their logical siblings are `&& || !` for "and, or, not", the logical "xor" doesn't have operator in C++.

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping me i got it.